# Is a .NET async TAP method allowed to be non async at all?

Tags: .net, asynchronous, async-await

Stephen Toub describes in his article "The Task-based Asynchronous Pattern" that async methods that implement the Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP) may even use a specific thread such as the UI thread to execute their code. That involves that async methods are allowed to use the calling thread. In this case the async method is not really async and blocks the calling thread. Is that really allowed? It wouldn’t make sense to create an async method that blocks the calling thread, or does it?

Here is the relevant clause of Stephen's article:

> **Target Environment**
>
> It is up to the TAP method’s implementation to determine where asynchronous execution occurs.  The developer of the TAP method may choose to execute the workload on the `ThreadPool`, may choose to implement it using asynchronous I/O and thus without being bound to a thread for the majority of the operation’s execution, may choose to run on a specific thread as need-be, such as the UI thread, or any number of other potential contexts.  It may even be the case that a TAP method has no execution to perform, returning a `Task` that simply represents the occurrence of a condition elsewhere in the system (e.g. a `Task<TData>` that represents `TData` arriving at a queued data structure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the method (or part of it) may need to run on the UI thread doesn't mean it has to block, whether you call it from the UI thread or not.

Imagine you have a method `Task DownloadAndShowData()`, that asynchronously downloads some data and then shows it in the UI. To show the downloaded data on the UI, it needs to execute some code on the UI thread. You could implement it something like this:

```
async Task DownloadAndShowData()
{
    var data = await DownloadData();
    await uiSchedulerFactory.StartNew(() => ShowData(data));
}
```

Here, `uiSchedulerFactory` is a `TaskFactory` that executes the code on the UI thread (using `SynchrnonizationContext`).

In this code, the returned `Task` is completed only after the data is shown in the UI, which used the UI thread. But the method itself doesn't block. If you have a code like:

```
await DownloadAndShowData();
// some more code
```

executing on the UI thread, what happens is that when the `await` is reached, the current method is “paused”, and the UI thread is freed. After the download finishes, `ShowData()` from above is executed on the UI thread (it can execute, there is nothing blocking the thread). After that is done, the calling method is “unpaused” and `// some more code` executes.

To sum up, an async method execute some code on the UI thread (which could also be where the calling code is executing), but the async method does not block.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I do not agree. How can it be that code that is executed in the UI thread does not block this thread? Maybe there is a misunderstanding in what blocking is. I double checked using a test app. When an async method schedules work to the UI thread the UI thread is definitely blocked. That means for example that a WPF window does not react on any user input as long as the "async" method is executed. See code in following comment.

Comment: Here is my test code:
private async void Demo()
{
   double result = await CalculateAsync(1000000000);
   MessageBox.Show("Result: " + result);
}

private Task<double> CalculateAsync(int number)
{
   TaskFactory uiSchedulerFactory = new TaskFactory(CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None,
      TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
   return uiSchedulerFactory.StartNew(() =>
   {
      double result = 0;
      for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++)
      {
         result += Math.Sqrt(i);
      }
      return result;
   });
}

Comment: The code that's executed on the UI thread does block it, but only for a short while. The thread is not blocked until the whole methods completes. I'll have a look at your example.

Comment: In your test code, you are performing long calculation on the UI thread, of course that will block it. But the `CalculateAsync()` method (or the `Demo()` method) itself doesn't block, it returns almost immediately. That's what I was talking about.

Comment: Well, the code was messed up in the comment. Here is the test project: http://www.juergen-bayer.net/downloads/async_Block_Test.zip

Comment: Yes. I execute a long calculation. That is because my actual question was if exactly that is allowed for an async method. According to Stephen's article it is!! Cite: "The developer of the TAP method may choose to execute the **workload** on the ThreadPool, may choose to implement it using asynchronous I/O and thus without being bound to a thread for the majority of the operation’s execution, may choose to run on a specific thread as need-be, such as the UI thread, or any number of other potential contexts.". Note that Stephen uses the term "workload" and not "code parts" or so.

Comment: Is it allowed? Yes. Is it a good idea? No. The quote doesn't say what kind of code you should or shouldn't execute on the UI thread, just that you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

A call to `await` a method that returns a `Task` object simply delegates to that task object to start the invocation of it's task.  From the caller of that task object's point of view, that task object may or may not have been already invoked.  If it was already invoked, it may be completed by the time `await` gets to it, in which case, from the code at await's point of view, the task executes synchronously.

That's one instance.  Another is that the `Task` knows what it needs to do; if what it needs to do can be done quicker synchronously it will simply do it synchronously.  One example may be receiving data from a remote source.  Many methods that receive data implement TAP, this is because data is being sent by a remote source and being received by your computer in the background.  Calling a method to receive a byte "asynchronously" might already have that byte and it would simply be easier to return the byte synchronously.  If, no bytes have been received yet then the method would run asynchronously waiting for a byte to be sent by the remote source.  When that byte was received, it would inform the caller asynchronously through the continuation or the code following the `await`.

Comment: Your second instance is a very good point that clarifies Stephen’s statement.

Comment: One minor correction: a `Task` object returned from a TAP method *must* have been started. It may or may not be complete, but it *cannot* be in the `TaskStatus.Created` state.

Answer (score -1):

You may find my [`async`/`await` intro helpful](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), particularly the parts discussing the "context".

A common example is to download some information, parse it into a data structure, and then update the UI, like this:

```
private async Task GetInfoAndUpdateUIAsync()
{
  var info = await GetInfoAsync();
  UpdateUI(info);
}

private async Task<MyInfo> GetInfoAsync()
{
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {
    var httpResponse = await client.GetStringAsync(...);
    return MyInfo.Parse(httpResponse);
  }
}
```

**Walkthrough**

You can call `GetInfoAndUpdateUIAsync` from the UI context (e.g., an `async void` event handler).

When `GetInfoAndUpdateUIAsync` starts executing, it executes (synchronously) on the UI thread. The first thing it does is call `GetInfoAsync`.

`GetInfoAsync` also starts executing (synchronously) on the UI thread. It creates an `HttpClient` and then uses it to start downloading some data from a URL. When `GetInfoAsync` performs its `await`, it saves its state and returns an incomplete `Task<MyInfo>` to `GetInfoAndUpdateUIAsync`.

`GetInfoAndUpdateUIAsync` does an `await` on the returned `Task<MyInfo>`, which is not complete. So it also saves *its* state and returns. This continues on back up to the original caller (e.g., an `async void` event handler). The UI thread is now free to do other work.

When the `HttpClient` finishes downloading the data, its returned `Task<string>` will complete. This will schedule the continuation of `GetInfoAsync` on the UI thread.

`GetInfoAsync` will then continue executing on the UI thread. It parses the response into a data structure (`MyInfo.Parse`) while running on the UI thread, and then reaches the end of the method, completing the `Task<MyInfo>` task it returned earlier.

When the `Task<MyInfo>` completes, it schedules the continuation of `GetInfoAndUpdateUIAsync` to the UI thread. `GetInfoAndUpdateUIAsync` then calls `UpdateUI(info)` (synchronously) on the UI thread.

**Conclusion**

This is an example where various parts of the `async` methods will execute (synchronously) on the UI thread, yet the UI thread is not *blocked*.

When `async` methods continue after they `await` a `Task`, they will resume in the same context by default. This "context" is the current `SynchronizationContext` (e.g., the UI context) if it is not null, otherwise it's the current `TaskScheduler`. You can override the default behavior by awaiting the result of `ConfigureAwait(false)`, which will cause the method continuation to run on a thread pool thread.

**One More Note**

In this example, we're doing some things on the UI thread that don't really have to be done on the UI thread. In particular, the parsing of the HTTP response into a `MyInfo` structure.

We can change `GetInfoAsync` to be a bit more efficient by overriding the default context capturing:

```
private async Task<MyInfo> GetInfoAsync()
{
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {
    var httpResponse = await client.GetStringAsync(...).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return MyInfo.Parse(httpResponse);
  }
}
```

Now, when the HTTP response comes in and `GetInfoAsync` continues executing, it will continue executing on a thread pool thread instead of the UI thread. So `MyInfo.Parse` will execute on the thread pool rather than the UI. When it's done parsing, the `Task<MyInfo>` will complete, and `GetInfoAndUpdateUIAsync` will continue executing on the UI thread.

We can't do the same thing with `GetInfoAndUpdateUIAsync`, because `UpdateUI` needs to run on the UI thread.

So this leads to a best practice: use `ConfigureAwait(false)` in your "library" `async` methods.

Comment: A method decorated with `async` is not itself asynchronous.  An `async` method is one that awaits another method that *could be* asynchronous (i.e. returns a `Task`-derived object).  He's talking about TAP: methods that return `Task` and how the `Task` can be executed synchronously, if needed.  This answer really has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer which is very informative. But it does not really answer my question. I was aware of how the synchronization context is handled. The actual problem was that it obviously is allowed that an async method not only execute code **parts** on the UI thread, but schedules **all** work to any thread, i.e. the UI thread (using a TaskFactory that works with the current sync context for example), and therefore blocks this thread for the time it is executed.

Comment: @Peter: Disagree. My answer clearly describes how `async` methods *may* be asynchronous. Also, tasks returned from TAP methods *cannot* be executed synchronously. By definition, if they have a delegate, they are already started before returning. (By the definition of TAP, I mean).

Comment: @JürgenBayer: `Is that really allowed?` Yes, but not recommended. `It wouldn’t make sense to create an async method that blocks the calling thread, or does it?` No, it does not.

Comment: @StephenCleary `Task`s can be a representation of a result, and thus are not executed asynchronously--they're not executed at all; but everything in that TAP implementation would have been executed synchronously (independent of `async`).  As soon as an `async` method returns without having executed all its code, it's asynchronous.  The fact that the rest of the code is run on the UI thread doesn't make it synchronous. Running at a "later time" makes it *asynchronous*.  But, irrelevant, TAP is independent from async/await and can be implemented without it. i.e. the question was about TAP.

Comment: @Peter: I think we're just disagreeing about semantics, here. `Task`s are a future, which can be code-based (with delegate) or not code-based (`TaskCompletionSource<T>`). Code-based `Task`s need to be executed, and all execution is synchronous with respect to the current thread. So you can schedule code to run on a thread, but when it runs, it runs synchronously. TAP (as defined by the Task-Based Asynchronous Pattern document) *can* be implemented without `async`/`await`, but it's usually easier to implement it *with* `async` (except for simple cases like `Task.FromResult`).

Comment: @StephenCleary You *can't* implement TAP with `async`  A "TAP method returns either a Task or a Task<TResult>..." and is "named with an “Async” suffix".  The `async` keyword just means you can use `await` on a TAP method. TAP was defined for TPL, before async/await.  You *use* TAP when you use async/await.  All code is synchronous in relation to the thread it is currently executing on.  What `async` means is that the entire invocation of the method body may not complete after the method returns to the thread that called it.  You can still have asynchronous and a single thread.

Comment: @PeterRitchie: The "TAP" I'm talking about is the only publicly-available  definition from Microsoft: the Task-Based Asynchronous Pattern document from Stephen Toub. It did not exist for the TPL; it was introduced alongside `async`. And *of course* you can use `async` to implement TAP - why *couldn't* you?